# POST request is returning ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY for coporate users

Tags: firewall, http, cloudflare, http2

We have a website and an api services on two different subdomains. Both running on Cloudflare.

The website that runs on `www.example.com`, and when the user logs in, there is an XHR POST call to `api.example.com/login`.

Seems like all is working fine, except that some of our corporate users get the following error:
`ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY`

I am wondering if this is something that is solely related to firewall blacklists or is there a way for our service to work under firewall restrictions for our corporate users.

Would perhaps placing the login endpoint under the same domain (`www.example.com/login`) would help? Perhaps changing some of Cloudflare's configuration would help?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does the error come from?

Comment: the customer's browser